# What is the best way to bypass the limitation for the allowed count of AWS CloudFormation Parameters?

Tags: parameters, aws-cloudformation

I already reached the number of 60 parameters in my CF template and looking for the best way to fix my problem. Any advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to reevaluate your template?

How bout packing them into a less parameters and then splitting them?

See:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Most of the values for parameters are dynamic and coming from an output. Is there any way to pack this type of parameters?

Comment: Use Fn::Join to concat

Comment: Was this helpful?  If so, can you mark as the answer.  If not, what else can I help with?